# A "for" loop is making my data == undefined

Tags: node.js, request

Im trying to make a appliation that finds quizzes on kahhot but when im running the code the
data is getting undefined even tho 2 lines before I get this data

- **First console.log**: card: {
  type: 'quiz',
  title: 'Guess Who',
  description: 'Start of term quiz to see how well the class know each other',
  slug: 'guess-who',
  cover: 'https://media.kahoot.it/e6740327-876d-4610-9fba-bc305f4bcae0_opt',
  coverMetadata: [Object],
  draftExists: false,
  number_of_questions: 38,
  creator: 'bfdca93b-efba-4ccb-a64d-c5538b24ba94',
  creator_username: 's_swan',
  creatorPrimaryUsageType: 'SCHOOL',
  creator_avatar: {},
  badges: [],
  visibility: 1,
  locked: false,
  writeProtection: false,
  featured: false,
  young_featured: false,
  sponsored: false,
  draft: false,
  combined: false,
  compatibility_level: 6,
  sample_questions: [Array],
  number_of_plays: 110,
  number_of_players: 274,
  total_favourites: 0,
  question_types: [Array],
  created: 1471873436135,
  modified: 1474121015925,
  access: [Object],
  duplication_disabled: false,
  uuid: 'b58c19b5-b098-4531-a1c6-e8e735e8f7b2'
  }
- **Second console.log()**: undefined

In the "for" loop the data are going to be undefined, how?

I have this code:

````
var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': 'https://create.kahoot.it/rest/kahoots/?query='+nam+'&cursor=0&limit=20&topics&grades=&orderBy=relevance&searchCluster=1&includeExtendedCounters=False',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
    }
};

// Starting the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
        
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var quizzes = data['entities'];
    console.log(quizzes);
    // Going the all the quzzies we found
    for(quiz in quizzes)  {
        card = quiz['card'];
        console.log(card);
    }
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue #1

Based on your first console.log, it looks like your `quizzes` variable is an object....not an array, so you're not iterating over an array of quizzes...you're iterating over an object...make sure your `quizzes` variable is an array first.

#### Issue #2

When you use the `for...in` statement, the `quiz` variable is going to return the name of each property in the object.

So if I just console.log the quiz variable, like this:

```
for(quiz in quizzes)  {
  console.log(card);
}
```

I would see all the properties logged to the console, like this:

```
type
title
description
slug
.....
```

#### Solution: Use a `for...of` statement

When you  use a `for...of` statement, the variable you set (`quiz` in your case) is the entire object.

So if I just console.log the quiz variable, like this:

```
for(const quiz of quizzes)  {
  console.log(quiz);
}
```

I would see this:

```
card: {
      type: 'quiz',
      title: 'Viet Nam War',
      description: 'Viet Nam War',
      slug: 'viet-nam-war',
      draftExists: false,
      number_of_questions: 37,
      creator: '01f63a9f-737b-4f59-b7f5-af10b78ce904',
      creator_username: 'Mr.TBrown',
      creatorPrimaryUsageType: 'SCHOOL',
      creator_avatar: {},
      badges: [],
      visibility: 1,
      locked: false,
      writeProtection: false,
      last_edit: [Object],
      featured: false,
      young_featured: false,
      sponsored: false,
      moderation: [Object],
      draft: false,
      combined: false,
      compatibility_level: 6,
      sample_questions: [Array],
      number_of_plays: 65,
      number_of_players: 169,
      total_favourites: 0,
      question_types: [Array],
      created: 1527781306997,
      modified: 1528072275324,
      access: [Object],
      duplication_disabled: false,
      uuid: 'cea8c609-ee88-4f11-b146-e8c70f302f14'
    }
```

See the following MDN docs for more examples:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Thx @GabrielMC but for some reason it doesn't change anything it didn't change anything

Comment: Sorry, I'm re-writing my answer now

Comment: K, take a look now. I tried to give a better explanation of why you need the `for...of`

Answer (score -1):

If you wanna loop over on array you normally want to use `for...of` instead of `for...in` and also you need to add a variable declaration (const or let).

```js
for(const quiz of quizzes)  {
    card = quiz['card'];
    console.log(card);
}
```